# Redistributable completion for my bash scripts

Tags: bash, shell-script, autocomplete

Is there a simple way to embed the completion features inside a script, for bash ?

I have a script that I want to redistribute, but I can't ask the people to add something inside their `/etc/bash_completion.d`  in order for them to get the completion working fot my script...

Comment: What's wrong with distributing a package?

Comment: It might require root rights, which my script doesn't need.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There isn't a standard location for bash completions in home directories. You can either instruct people to copy your completion code into their `.bashrc`, or instruct them to save your completion definition script somewhere (which should not be on their `$PATH`) and to source it from their `.bashrc`. I recommend the latter since it makes upgrades a lot easier.

```
. ~/.bash_completions/jmc_app
```

Conventionally, your completions should be defined in a script with the same name as the program it completes for, containing a function definition with the same name with an underscore prepended, and calling `complete` to install the completion:

```
# jmc_app completion
_jmc_app () {
  …
}
complete -F _jmc_app jmc_app
```

Comment: this will have to do! does anyone knows if there is a better mechanism in zsh for instance ?